# how to display each gallery image in category page

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

i want to make categories gallery. so i have one category called **gallery**, i create some post with gallery images. in gallery category page i want to display each post 4 picture. picture will take from advancedcustomfields gallery field.  bellow is my current category-gallery page code, image not coming but title and more link working fine. would guys tell me what how to do ?

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="contentarea">
  <div class="wapper">
    <div class="content clearfix">
      <?php 
    while ( have_posts() ) :
    the_post();
    $images = get_field('gallery_picture');

    ?>
      <h2><a href="<?php  the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php  the_title(); ?>
        </a></h2>
      <a href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>"> <img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" /> </a> <a href="<?php  the_permalink(); ?>" class="info">Gallery</a> </div>
    <?php  endwhile; ?>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: When you put the `print_r($images);` under the `$images` variable, what comes out? And when you inspect the DOM, is there anything inside the anchor where you've echoed the url and image?

Comment: problem solve . thanks for support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve this problem. so want to share with other. this for category page. bellow is code

```
      <?php 
    while ( have_posts() ) :
    the_post();


    ?>
      <h2><a href="<?php  the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php  the_title(); ?>
        </a></h2>
      <?php
$images = get_field('gallery_picture');
$max = 5;
$i = 0;

if( $images ): ?>
      <ul>
        <?php foreach( $images as $image ): $i++; ?>
        <?php if( $i > $max){ break; } ?>
        <li> <img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" /> </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </ul>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <a href="<?php  the_permalink(); ?>" class="info">Gallery</a> </div>
    <?php  endwhile; ?>
```